# Clear interval not working on javascript timer

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", move);

function move(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      x = x - speed;
      break;
    case 38:
      // up key pressed
      y = y - speed
      break;
    case 39:
      x = x + speed
      break;
    case 40:
      y = y + speed
      break;
    case 32:
      if (iTouched == true) {
        startCounter();
      }
      break;
  }
  sendData();
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", getStuff);

function getStuff(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32:
      if (iTouched == true) {
        shoot();
      }
      break;
  }

}

function startCounter() {
  function count() {
    time += 1
    console.log(time)
  }
  interval = setInterval(count, 100)
}

function shoot() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}
```

The startCounter() function is triggered by a keydown event listener and the shoot() function is triggered by a keyup event listener. For some reason the setInterval will not stop when I lift the key up. The shoot() function works with other commands like an alert() just not the clearInterval(). Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The MCVE that was edited in works fine. Please post your actual code so we can see the full picture.

Comment: The code you've provided does work. The issues you are having must be caused by another part of the program. Please provide code for "The startTimer() function is triggered by a keydown event listener and the stop() function is triggered by a keyup event listener."

Comment: @Olian04 I rolled back your edit because it doesn't have the problem the OP describes. He must be binding handlers differently, and that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough.

Comment: Do you know how to look at your console log in your browser? Are there any errors showing up there?

Comment: Sounds like it is called more than once.... so call stop() inside of startTimer before creating a new one.

Comment: What is `iTouched`? Where is `sendData`? They are not defined anywhere

Comment: Your new code doesn't have `startTimer` or `stop` functions, they've been renamed to `startCounter` and `shoot`. It also calls a function `sendData()` that isn't defined.

Comment: Solution was simple before your edit but now `sendData()` and `iTouched` are not defined. What are they?

Comment: keydown fires more than once... pretty simple to see with a console.log()

Comment: sendData sends data to a firebase realtime Database which works fine and iTouched is a variable that checks if the player has the ball which also works fine. I renamed the functions earlier to make it easier to understand what I was doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keydown fires multiple times as you hold down the key.

```js
var bod = document.body;
bod.addEventListener("keydown", () => console.log('keydown', new Date()))
bod.addEventListener("keyup", () => console.log('keyup', new Date()))
```

So you create more than one interval so you overwrite the last one. So you need to clear the interval before you create a new one

```
if (interval) clearInterval(interval)
interval = setInterval(count, 100)
```

or do not create one if it exists

```
if (!interval) {
   interval = setInterval(count, 100)
}
```

and when you clear it

```
function shoot() {
  clearInterval(interval)
  interval = null
}
```